# Validate reachability of each state in a FSM from a 'start' state and to an 'end' state

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am starting with a FSM with N states (i.e. N vertices on the state diagram graph).
Of these one state is the 'start' state and one state is the 'end' state.

What I would like to do is -

1. check whether each of the other N-2 states is reachable from the 'start' state
2. check if the 'end' state is reachable from each of the N-2 states

What is the best algorithm to achieve this goal?
Also, are there any Python module(s) which would do this validation with minimal effort (like just a single function call)?

Comment: @user189 - No. BFS and DFS had completely skipped my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Python module [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) which helped me tremendously.
[This](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html) (networkx.shortest_path) specifically is the function I used.

Pasting below the solution which worked for me.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(["Start", "a", "b", "c", "End"])
G.add_edges_from([("Start", "a"), ("Start", "c"), ("a", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("c", "End")])

total_num_nodes = G.number_of_nodes()

if len(nx.shortest_path(G, source="Start")) < total_num_nodes:
    print "\nThis FSM has inaccessible states"
else:
    print "\nAll nodes reachable from 'Start'"

H = G.reverse()
if len(nx.shortest_path(H, source="End")) < total_num_nodes:
    print "\nThis FSM has dead-end states"
else:
    print "\nAll nodes have a path to reach the 'End' state"
```

Comment: Then, it is probably a BFS \o/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any travesal (DFS/BFS/…) from the start state and mark visited states as reachable. For the coreachability problem, just reverse edges and start from the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That reversing of the graph thing seems obvious now that you told it, but it hadn't crossed my mind yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple solution, you can compute the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the FSM's transition function using the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). That will give you an `NxN` array telling you for any two states `P` and `Q` whether `Q` is reachable from `P`. It takes `O(N3)`, which should be fine if `N` is not too large.

The algorithm can be written in exactly five lines of python. Here `trans` is a list of lists such that `trans[s][t]` is `True` if there is a direct transition from `s` to `t`, and otherwise `False`. (`s` and `t` are expected to be integers). It modifies this array in place; when it returns, `trans[s][t]` is `True` if there is a path from `s` to `t`:

```
def warshall(trans):
  for k in range(len(trans)):
    for i in range(len(trans)):
      for j in range(len(trans)):
        trans[i][j] = trans[i][j] or trans[i][k] and trans[k][j]
```

(The last line could have been written with `|=` but I think that's less clear.)

This algorithm can also be used to compute the "all shortest paths" array, and it's usually cited as a solution to this problem. To do this, we start with a transition array where `trans[i][j]` is the cost of the transition from `i` to `j` (`infinity` if there is no direct transition), and replace the last line with:

```
        trans[i][j] = min(trans[i][j], trans[i][k] + trans[k][j])
```

For an FSM, you would normally set all the costs to either `1` or `infinity`, and then you'll end up with the length of the shortest path from `s` to `t` for any `s` and `t`.

You'll find formal proofs of the algorithm all over the internet (and in standard textbooks on algorithms and graph theory), so I'll just do the outline:

To simplify typing, I'm going to pretend that nodes are represented by integers in the range `0…N-1`. We'll call a path `s→p0→…→pi→t` a `<k`-path if every `p0…pi` is less than `k`. Consequently the only possible `<0`-path from `s` to `t` is the trivial path `s→t`, if it exists in the graph, and every path from `s` to `t` is a `<N`-path.

Now, if there is a `<k+1`-path from `s` to `t`, then either there is a `<k`-path from `s` to `t`, or there is a `<k`-path from `s` to `k` and another `<k`-path from `k` to `t`. (That's just another way of saying that every non-singular path has a maximum internal node, and can be divided at that node into two paths whose maxima are smaller.)

Each iteration of the Warshall algorithm starts with the transition array of `<k`-paths and ends with the transition array of `<k+1`-paths, by adding all the combinations of paths through node `k`. So at the end, we have the array of `<N`-paths, which, as we observed earlier, includes every possible path.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
I found a module (namely Networkx) yesterday which provides a direct api to this algorithm ([networkx.floyd_warshall](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall)).